# Curve with arc length have signed curvature k(s)>0?

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature

Let $g:I \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a curve such that for all $s \in I$, $\|g'(s)\|=1$ and $\kappa_g(s) \neq 0$, where $\kappa_g$ is the signed curvature of $g$. Is $\kappa_g(s) \gt 0$ for all $s \in I$? thanks!

Comment: Counterexample: A straight curve.

Comment: if we know that k(s) is not 0 for every s at I?

Comment: Is that a part of the question you should maybe have added in the first place?

Comment: yes of course , i am sorry.

Comment: Also there is no such thing as signed curvature in 3D space.

Comment: By "$k(s)$ is not $0$ for every $s$" do you mean: $(\forall \ s)(k(s) \neq 0)$ or $(\exists \ s)(k(s) \neq 0)$?

Comment: you are right , sorru again. So in $R^2$ ?

Comment: @AhmedHussein  (∀ s)(k(s)≠0)

Comment: Also I suppose that there is at least one point $s_0$ on your curve with positive signed curvature?

Comment: no then  it is obvious that k(s)>0 , isn't it?

Comment: i think i get it . we can get that k(s)>0 or k(s)<0 if k(s)≠0 (∀ s)  ,right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If for all $s \in I$, $k(s) \neq 0$, then using IVT (as the signed curvature is a continuous function) either $k(s) > 0$ for all $s \in I$ or $k(s) < 0$ for all $s \in I$. We can't conclude that $k(s) > 0$ for all $s \in I$ because it is also possible that $k(s) < 0$ for all $s \in I$.

For instance, $t \in (0,2\pi) \mapsto (\cos t, -\sin t)$ has a strictly negative signed curvature everywhere.

The signed curvature depends on the orientation of the curve. From a curve with strictly positive signed curvature, you can extract a curve with strictly negative signed curvature just by changing its orientation.

Comment: thank you for your answer!